# how can I correct this restructured text syntax issue?

Tags: restructuredtext

In [the README.rst for blargs](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gyllstromk/blargs/master/README.rst) we see an syntactic error in [the first sentence of the Quick Start section](https://github.com/gyllstromk/blargs/blob/master/README.rst#quick-start) - specifically we see `:class:` rendered instead of only seeing `Parser`.

The actual code of that sentence is:

```
The preferred use of :class:`Parser` is via the ``with`` idiom, as follows:
```

How do we fix that syntax so that it correctly renders and what part of the restructured text docs informs us about this?

Comment: Also [further down](https://github.com/gyllstromk/blargs/blob/master/README.rst#unless) we see `:meth:` literally rendered instead of being used as a formatting hint. This needs to be fixed too.

Comment: [Even further down](https://github.com/gyllstromk/blargs/blob/master/README.rst#indicating-label-style) there is `:py:meth:` which also needs to be fixed. How would you fix this?

Comment: `class` and `meth` are Sphinx-specific roles. They are probably not understood by the ReST processor used by GitHub.